# Как улавливать номер телефона в aiogram?

Tags: python, бот, aiogram, int

Только учусь кодить на aiogram, перерыл пару десятков сайтов, но так и не нашел ответ. Мне необходимо чтобы когда пользователь отправляет int-овое значение, к примеру: номер телефона, бот ловил его через massage_handler

Answer (score 2):

Пример кнопки:

```
markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(
    KeyboardButton(
        text='ur text',
        request_contact=True
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярных выражений, эта задача легко решается.

```
import re
text = "Вот мой номер +77777777777"

def detect_phone_number(text):
    phone_number = re.findall('(?:\+ *)?\d[\d\- ]{7,}\d', text)
    print(phone_number)
    print(phone_number[0])

def main():
    detect_phone_number(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже поздно, но если кому-то понадобится, то вот:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def message(msg: types.Message):
    if 'entities' in msg:
        for i in msg['entities']: 
            if i['type'] == 'phone_number':
                phoneNumber = msg.text[i['offset']:i['offset']+i['length']]
                await msg.answer(phoneNumber)
```

Отправляет в обратных сообщениях все номера телефонов (отдельно).
Можно добавлять каждый номер в массив, это уже на ваше усмотрение.